# Suggestion for routes from California to Italy?

Tags: airports, italy, routes, california

I noticed there are no direct flights from USA west coast to Italy. All have connections, but all the routes still end up on Italy's international airports. But mostly because I am searching for flights ending on those airports.

I know flights between Schengen countries often go to smaller airports too. But you have to know the final airport because ticket purchasing sites won't let you search for country. (I'd love to be told otherwise on this btw!)

Since the international ones are far away from my destination anyway, i'd like to try and search for routes ending on the smaller airports to see if I can find better prices and/or better proximity to my actual destination in Calabria.

What are some airports other than Milan, Rome and Naples that are also the last leg of international flights from California (LAX and others) that you know of?

Comment: How do you call this off-topic for Travel?  SkyScanner and Azuon and Adioso will let you search an entire country.  And Azuon will let you say "Europe" (or list multiple countries).  Rome2Rio will let you say a country or continent but it internally treats it as a single point within that area.

Answer (score 1):

There are many small international airports in Italy. Verona Villafranca Airport, Venice Marco Polo Airport, Genoa Cristoforo Colombo Airport, are just few of them.

You could use web apps like [momondo](https://www.momondo.com/) and do a query enabling the option for "*include nearby airports*". Have a look at [this](https://www.momondo.com/flights/lax-1/it-4/flights-from-los-angeles-intl-to-italy.html?TripType=2&SegNo=2&SDP0=25-05-2017&SDP1=29-05-2017&AD=1&TK=ECO&DO=false&NA=true) one for example. In this way you will have a clue of what are the other available airports.

Comment: thanks. that site conveniently suggest other airports i can then search for. And I just found out Alitalia have direct flights to all those lesser-known airports from LAX, but they all start at double the price of alternatives to FCO.

Comment: true, Alitalia does connect to most smaller airports and the prices get unnecessarily high sometimes; see if you can find in other cheaper airlines like: EasyJet, Vueling, RyanAir. Some of them operate in smaller airports.